# .NET - Enabling migrations and updating database

Tags: .net, entity-framework-migrations

I had developed a project using .NET MVC and Entity Framework. It was working fine. I have formatted the laptop, have reinstalled Visual Studio and I am trying enable migrations and update database. I get the following error

```
PM> update-database -ConfigurationType MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
The type 'MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.
```

I have checked the following and it looks good. I am not sure why the above error occurs.

1. Entity Framework is installed and it is available to the solution / 
   project
2. The correct connection string is available in the Web.config file
3. I can enable migrations and getting the error while updating
   the database
4. I can successfully enable code migrations and update database for one other solution and could not enable for the solution which is working fine earlier. No change is made to the project post that.

I have explored existing links and have tried those options. I could not find out a solution

The error message is same if I run it with -verbose flag and the details are given below

```
PM> update-database -verbose -ConfigurationType MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext
Using StartUp project 'MessageBoard'.
Using NuGet project 'MessageBoard'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException: The type 'MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions.CreateInstance[T](Type type, Func`3 typeMessageFactory, Func`2 exceptionFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The type 'MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.
```

Comment: Have you run it with the verbose flag as the error message suggests? If so, posting that output may help

Comment: I have added the error message with verbose flag

Comment: Can you validate that `MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext` inherits `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`?

Comment: Yes. I have validated. The MessageBoardContext uses DbContext and the package System.Data.Entity is imported. The class is compiled without any issues

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh It's inheriting, but the error still appears. The calls inherits from DbContext and required Entity package is imported

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong parameter to point at the context. -ConfigurationType expects the migration configuration, not a context.

Change the project in package manager console drop down to the one with migrations before running `update-database`

https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the command and it is giving the following error   PM> update-database -ContextTypeName MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext
Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ContextTypeName'.
At line:1 char:33
+ update-database -ContextTypeName <<<<  MessageBoard.Data.MessageBoardContext
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-Database], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Update-Database

Comment: See edit. You should be able to just run regular update-database as long as you change the project.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it is not working for the project and it is working for other projects with the same installation.